# Angular factory function not reached.

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I'm learning how to use Angularjs with ROR through this tutorial https://thinkster.io/angulartutorial/angular-rails/

I've come to a point where when I'm adding a new function for a service which is supposed to get all posts we have in the db. However When I run the code the page does not load anymore. Or at least the html is not rendered. There is no indication of errors in the elements inspections. However I'm not sure it has to do with the placing of the function in the js file. I'm totally new to js and I still struggle to read the sintax and spot errors in the code. Rubymine has given a clue with and Unreacheble code warning for the o.getAll. If someone could have a look at it and give me any hints it would be great.

Apologies to all the code in one file both html and js. I'm having some issues with the assets pipeline that I mean to get fixed soon.

app.js

> Blockquote

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router'])
//Provider
.config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: '/home.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    postPromise: ['posts', function(posts){
                        return posts.getAll();
                    }]
                }
            })
            .state('posts', {
                url: '/posts/{id}',
                templateUrl: '/posts.html',
                controller: 'PostsCtrl'
            })

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
    }])
//Posts service
.factory('posts', ['$http', function($http){

    var o = {
        posts: []
    };
    return o;

    o.getAll = function() {
        return $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data){
            angular.copy(data, o.posts);
        });
    };


}])

//Main Controller
.controller('MainCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    'posts',

    function($scope, posts){
        $scope.posts = posts.posts;
        $scope.addPost = function(){
            if(!$scope.title  || $scope.title == '') { return; }
            $scope.posts.push({
                title: $scope.title,
                link: $scope.link,
                upvotes: 0,
                comments: [
                    {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
                    {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
                ]
            });
            $scope.title = '';
            $scope.link = '';
        };
        $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
            post.upvotes += 1;
        };

    }])
//Posts Controller
.controller('PostsCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    '$stateParams',
    'posts',
    function($scope, $stateParams, posts){
        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];

        $scope.addComment = function(){
            if($scope.body === '') { return; }
            $scope.post.comments.push({
                body: $scope.body,
                author: 'user',
                upvotes: 0
            });
            $scope.body = '';
        };}]);
```

>
and following the application.html.erb

```
> Blockquote

<html>
<head>


  <title>FlapperNews</title>

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>
  <script src="javascripts/application.js"></script>

  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Flapper News</h1>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
            ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
    {{post.upvotes}}
      <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
          {{post.title}}
        </a>
        <span ng-hide="post.link">
          {{post.title}}
        </span>
      </span>
      <span>
        <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
      </span>
  </div>

  <form ng-submit="addPost()"
        style="margin-top:30px;">
    <h3>Add a new post</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             placeholder="Title"
             ng-model="title">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             placeholder="Link"
             ng-model="link">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
  </form>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.html">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h3>
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
      </a>
        <span ng-hide="post.link">
          {{post.title}}
        </span>
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
            ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
    {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
      <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        {{comment.body}}
      </span>
  </div>
  <form ng-submit="addComment()"
        style="margin-top:30px;">
    <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text"
             class="form-control"
             placeholder="Comment"
             ng-model="body">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
  </form>

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `factory` you are returning `o` before the `getAll` function so it is unreachable

```
 .factory('posts', ['$http', function($http){

   var o = {
     posts: []
   };

   //removed return 

   o.getAll = function() {
      return $http.get('/posts.json').success(function(data){
         angular.copy(data, o.posts);
      });
   };

  return o; //at the added return 
 }])
```

Comment: @vinibol12 : You are welcome. You can upvote and accept as an answer, if answer has helped.

Comment: will do it for sure. It's just that you answered less then 10 min after I posted so it seems to have a minimum time before I can accept it.